# When using the <exception> class, the what() function seems to not be working properly

Tags: c++

in this particular program I implemented a deque. the only problem seems to be my error handling. here is the relevant code:

```
#include <exception>

class Deque {
    public:
        class RemoveError : exception {
            public:
                 virtual const char* what() const noexcept {
                     return "error: cannot remove element; the queue is empty";
            }
        }R_error;

        T removeFirst() throw(RemoveError);
};

Deque::removeFirst() throw(RemoveError) {
    if (isEmpty()) 
        { throw R_error; }
}

int main () {
    try {
        Deque Q;
        printf ( "this should be an error :%d\n", Q.removeFirst ( ) );
    }
    catch(exception& e) {
        printf ( e.what(), '\n');
    }
}
```

and yet, when I deliberately try to remove one too many nodes from my deque, the error on the screen is

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Deque::RemoveError

instead of

> error: cannot remove element; the queue is empty

I have tried both using and not using the `virtual` in my `what()` function, and I tried throwing `RemoveError()` instead of `R_error`.

is there any reason this is happening? I tried to find an answer on here but couldn't find this particular problem.

edit: as noted below, I had my exceptions private; changing

```
class RemoveError : exception {
```

to either

```
struct RemoveError : exception {
class RemoveError : public exception {
```

fixed it. Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: You have to catch the exception somewhere and print the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message gets produced by g++ default uncaught exception handler, see [Verbose Terminate Handler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/termination.html#support.termination.verbose):

> The __verbose_terminate_handler function obtains the name of the current exception, attempts to demangle it, and prints it to stderr. If the exception is derived from exception then the output from what() will be included.

But in:

```
class RemoveError : exception
```

`std::exception` is not a **public** base class of `RemoveError`, hence that exception handler cannot call its `what` function.

Fix:

```
class RemoveError : public exception
```

Or:

```
struct RemoveError : exception
```

---

Note 1:

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept
```

Should be:

```
const char* what() const noexcept override
```

---

Note 2:

```
T removeFirst() throw(RemoveError);
```

Exception specification is depricated in C++11. That should be just plain:

```
T removeFirst();
```

Comment: `what` is OK, the changes you propose are stylistic.

Comment: @MSalters You are mistaken.

Comment: You may want to back up that assertion: `virtual` does not need to be repeated in overriders ( [`virtual`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) ) and `override` is optional. ( [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) )

Comment: I see two changes that you propose to the declaration of the `what` override: You remove `virtual` (stylistic, the keyword is optional in overriders) and you add `override` (stylistic, also optional in overriders).

Comment: @MSalters Right, there are 3 notes in my post. The first one fixes the OP problem.

Comment: @MSalters `override` is not stylistic in the sense that it prevents signature mismatch, whereas `virtual` does not.

Comment: thanks, you were right on all accounts. ill update my post with the relevant info

Answer (score 1):

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'Deque::RemoveError'

`std::terminate` was called as there was an active exception that, through stack unwinding, was not caught.
In order to retrieve the message thrown along with the exception you have to catch the exception somewhere and call `what`.

```
{
    try {
        // code that might throw
    } catch(RemoveError e) {
       std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Catch by (const) reference to avoid possible slicing issue.